# How to change the position of the product video on the single product page on WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the old WooCommerce method to place the product video on the Single Product Page next to the product image gallery.

The hook below is being used on the **functions.php** page

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_my_video_product_gallery', 'add_product_video');

function add_product_video(){
    global $product;

    if($product->get_id() == 760){
    echo '<iframe class="responsive-iframevideo" name="product01" id="product01" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDGDsX3qsaI" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0"></iframe>'; ;} }
```

And the other Hook is inserted in the file - path:
`\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\tabs\tabs.php`

and you can make the reference of the Hook in line 22:
`do_action("woocommerce_add_my_video_product_gallery");`

The Result is this:

[image]

**The problem is**: When we change the viewing for the Mobile View, the product video is being pushed to be displayed below the **Product title and Product description** as shown in the screenshot. With this error, we can lose the customer's attention and the sale because we have up to 5 seconds to capture their attention with the product video. And I'm sure hundreds of hundreds of people are interested to have the product video positioned below the product gallery.

[image]

I've already tested using priority action in the hook, but nothing happens.

**$priority int Optional**
Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed.
Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
**Default: 10**

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_my_video_product_gallery', 'add_product_video',10);
```

I've already tested using the **single product summary** hook, but in the mobile version...
The video is displayed below the gallery. And between the product video and the image gallery, the page breadcrum is displayed. In the desktop view, is also complicated because the product video  will be displayed between the breadcrumb and the product title.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','product_video_01');
```

[image]

When we use the Hook...

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_my_video_product_gallery', 'add_product_video');
```

How can we display or push the **product video** to the top of the page so that it can be displayed below the gallery on the mobile view version?

Maybe using a CSS trick this can be done, but I haven't figured out how yet. Or maybe using another hook.

This is the **iframe** that receives the video. Maybe with a **JavaScript** ou a **JQuery**, we can achieve the goel.

```
<iframe class="responsive-iframevideo" name="product01" id="product01" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDGDsX3qsaI" border="0" cellspacing="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have already tested a plugin for this functionality and I will not mention the name of the plugin here to place product videos within the product gallery, but the performance of loading images and videos when loading the product single page is terrible.